# how to set static ip in windows wireless settings

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking

I don't want my wireless router's automatic DHCP.

I'm using Windows XP; how can I connect to the router with a static IP?

Answer (score 1):

In case your router accepts a static IP (without any further ado). Go to *Control Panel* → *Network Connections*:

[image]

Right click on your WiFi card, *Properties*, edit the `TCP/IP` settings.

If your router won't work like this, then set it back to automatic (the way it was).
Then go to the router's webadmin page, and use the "static DHCP" option to assign yourself a static IP.